# cURL Authentication with PHP

Tags: php, authentication, curl

I need to establish authentication using cURL within my basic PHP application. I'm attempting to authenticate with the Springboard Retail API.

Their documentation, which can be found here: dev.springboardretail.com, indicates the following code for authentication using cURL:

```
curl -c cookiefile -b cookiefile -dauth_key={{username}}\&password={{password}} "https://{{subdomain}}.myspringboard.us/api/auth/identity/callback"
```

I can't seem to locate information on how the aforementioned code needs to be implemented. Here's my attempt:

```
<?php
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'dauth_key={{username}}\&password={{password}}');
    curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    $url = 'https://{{subdomain}}.myspringboard.us/api/auth/identity/callback';

    $result = curl_exec ($curl);
    curl_close ($curl);
    print $result;
?>
```

As I have no experience with cURL and basic PHP skills, please provide any comments or advice you may have. Thank you!

Comment: Start by replacing all the `{{xxxx}}` to their real values. Then you need to create the `$url` variable before you use it in your script. Now you create it after it's used...

Comment: I strongly suggest you rerun your curl command line with `--libcurl example.c` added and you'll see what options it uses and that it doesn't match what you tried...